# How to flatten a one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, talend, dimensional-modeling

While trying to build a data warehousing application using Talend, we are faced with the following  scenario.

We have two tables tables that look like

Table master

```
ID | CUST_NAME | CUST_EMAIL
------------------------------------
1  | FOO       | FOO_BAR@EXAMPLE.COM
```

Events Table

```
ID | CUST_ID | EVENT_NAME  | EVENT_DATE      
---------------------------------------
1  | 1       | ACC_APPLIED | 2014-01-01
2  | 1       | ACC_OPENED  | 2014-01-02
3  | 1       | ACC_CLOSED  | 2014-01-02
```

There is a one-to-many relationship between master and the events table.Since, given a limited number of event names I proposing that we denormalize this structure into something that looks like

```
ID | CUST_NAME | CUST_EMAIL          | ACC_APP_DATE_ID | ACC_OPEN_DATE_ID |ACC_CLOSE_DATE_ID      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | FOO       | FOO_BAR@EXAMPLE.COM | 20140101        | 20140102         | 20140103
```

THE `DATE_ID` columns refer to entries inside the time dimension table.

First question : Is this a good idea ? What are the other alternatives to this scheme ?

Second question : How do I implement this using Talend Open Studio ? I figured out a way in which I moved the data for each event name into it's own temporary table along with cust_id using the `tMap` component and later linked them together using another `tMap`. Is there another way to do this in talend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in Talend you'll need to first sort your data so that it is reliably in the order of applied, opened and closed for each account and then denormalize it to a single row with a single delimited field for the dates using the tDenormalizeRows component.

After this you'll want to use tExtractDelimitedFields to split the single dates field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That would work too. How about using the tPivotToColumnsDelimited component ?

Comment: tPivotToColumnsDelimited outputs a delimited file so isn't suitable for what you want. Arguably you could output a temporary file and then read it back in but it's messy and unnecessary for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this is a good idea, this is called a cumulative snapshot fact. http://www.kimballgroup.com/2012/05/design-tip-145-time-stamping-accumulating-snapshot-fact-tables/
Not sure how to do this in Talend (dont know the tool) but it would be quite easy to implement in SQL using a Case or Pivot statement

Answer (score 1):

Regarding only your first question, it's certainly a good idea -- unless there is any possibility of the same persons applying-opening-closing their account more than once *AND* you want to keep all this information in their history (so UPDATE wouldn't help).

Comment: Thanks for your input. But that won't be a problem as the real structure contains a natural key for each account holder..

Answer (score 1):

Snowflaking is definitely not a good option if you are going to design a data warehouse. So, denormalizing will certainly be a good choice in this case. Following article almost fits perfectly to clear the air over such scenarios,

http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/09/design-tip-105-snowflakes-outriggers-and-bridges/